# Get Periods of dates from SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datetime

I have dates and  I want to retrieve periods of dates.

I have table LeaveMaster:

```
ID    LeaveDate 
1     23/09/2015  
1     24/09/2015
1     25/09/2015
1     27/09/2015
1     29/09/2015
1     30/09/2015
1     01/10/2015
1     02/10/2015
1     04/10/2015
```

The result should be:

```
ID    StartDate     EndDate
1     23/09/2015    25/09/2015
1     27/09/2015    27/09/2015
1     29/09/2015    02/10/2015
1     04/10/2015    04/10/2015
```

How to solve this ?

Comment: Er, what? What is the logic behind your pairings? What makes 23/09/2015 a start date? What makes 25/09/2015 an end date? What makes 25/09/2015 the end date for 23/09/2015? Why are 27/09/2015 and 04/10/2015 both start and end date? And what is it you actually what to *exclude*? (Or did you only grab the wrong word for what you wanted to express?)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Guess he wants to group the continuous dates and display as range.

Comment: @Eric: Wow, that's well-spotted. Yes, you must be right.

Comment: @Kiran, what do you mean periods here?

Comment: Hm, if it's date ranges, why is it 29/09/2015 - 30/09/2015 and 01/10/2015 - 02/10/2015 rather than 29/09/2015 - 02/10/2015? Some extra logic for a month change or a mistake in the sample results?

Comment: Thanks advance, I have changed output of my question. please check and reply me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick to find consecutive values is to build a group key by subtracting the records position from the value. Then group by that key and show its min and max value.

```
select id, min(leavedate) as startdate, max(leavedate) as enddate
from
(
  select 
    id, 
    leavedate,
    dateadd(day, - row_number() over (partition by id order by leavedate), leavedate)
      as groupkey
  from leavemaster
) dates
group by id, groupkey, datepart(year, leavedate), datepart(month, leavedate);
```

In your example you show that you also want a new range for a new month, so I added `datepart(year, leavedate), datepart(month, leavedate)` to the GROUP BY clause. Remove this, if it was just a mistake.

Execute the inner query alone to see how it works.

Comment: Million Thanks @Thorsten Kettner, i vl check n let you konw

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT ID, 
       MIN(LeaveDate) AS StartDate,
       MAX(LeaveDate) AS EndDate
FROM (
  SELECT ID, LeaveDate,
         DATEDIFF(d, '19000101', LeaveDate) -
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LeaveDate) AS grp
  FROM mytable ) AS t
GROUP BY ID, grp
```

`grp` is used to identify slices of rows with *consecutive*  `LeaveDate` values. Using this field in a `GROUP BY` clause we can perform aggregate functions on each slice and get start / end dates.

**Note:** This works fine for intervals related to just *consecutive*  `LeaveDate` values. It doesn't identify interval splits due to month changes.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/766d0a/3)

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I quickly whipped up using cursors and temporary tables in T-Sql. Surely, It's not the most effective solution, but does the trick.

```
DECLARE @date DATE
DECLARE @lastdate DATE
DECLARE @spantbl TABLE(StartDate date, EndDate date)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT LeaveDate
FROM LeaveMaster
ORDER BY LeaveDate

OPEN db_cursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @date

INSERT INTO @spantbl VALUES(@date,NULL)

SET @lastdate = @date
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF DATEDIFF(d,@lastdate,@date) > 1
        BEGIN
            UPDATE @spantbl SET EndDate = @lastdate WHERE EndDate IS NULL
            INSERT INTO @spantbl VALUES(@date,NULL)
        END          
    SET @lastdate = @date
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @date
END

UPDATE @spantbl SET EndDate = @lastdate WHERE EndDate IS NULL

SELECT *
FROM @spantbl

CLOSE db_cursor 
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

And again, I'm not a professional. Just learned about cursors and put them to use :)